# How to nest block elements inside an inline context in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

I ran into a problem where I have to embed block level content directly inside a h1-h6 context. From the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values) I take that this has been ruled out to ensure compatibility with the default styles. Consequently, my code will not validate as HTML5. (However, it display perfectly in any browser I tested.)

I sketched my scenario in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3r3X/).

Is there any way to nest block elements inside inline elements in a HTML5 conform way? I could imagine an element that switches from inline to block context but will, by default, not be displayed; I just don't know such an element.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I know that JavaScript is capable of handling my example, but my solution has to be plain HTML+CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For content of that nature, you shouldn't be using `<h[1-6]>`. Use `<header>` instead.

Comment: Why *replace* the h# tag?  He still has a title there.  Though I would argue that the footer tag might be more appropriate for the content in question.

Comment: @cimmanon - Because the drop-down is not part of the heading according to the semantics of the h# elements. The technique being is cute, but it is not compatible with HTML5 semantics.

Comment: My comment does not imply that the markup should not be adjusted, just that the h2 is still appropriate since he has a title.  There is no way to create what he wants that is semantically correct, valid HTML, and has the visual appearance he is after.  If it is not a true title, then by all means replace.

Comment: I may not like it, but this seems to be the way I have to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly can't you use `spans`? Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/xVutp/).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, spans, as inline elements, may not contain block elements (such as p, ul, ...) either.

Comment: @MRA Yes, that's another issue. You can try simulating the `ul` looks using `&bullet;`, and create line breaks using `<br/>`.

Comment: True, but this is something I'd rather like to avoid. I would have to find a workaround for each and every content tag that might end up in the in the pop-up box. Although, it is a kind of "last resort" option.